# Random numbered array gives the same number

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I'm attempting to generate two arrays of random numbers. One array for height and the other for width of a text-art fish tank. But the arrays always have the same repeated number.

ex: [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ] or [ 9, 9, 9]

I must be setting up the loop incorrectly, but I need help to see what's wrong.

```
    //Generate random numbers for fish positions in vector
    if ( fish_collection.size() != 0 )
    {
        int randHeight[fish_collection.size()];
        int randWidth[fish_collection.size()];

        for ( int i = 0; i < fish_collection.size(); i++ )
        {
            srand (time(NULL));
            randHeight[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            randWidth[i] = rand() % (tank_size - 5) + 1;
        }

        //random number printed test
        for ( int i = 0; i < fish_collection.size(); i++ )
        {
            cout << randWidth[i] << ',';
        }
        cout << endl;

        //Enter the fish in random position
        for ( int j = 0; j < fish_collection.size(); j++ )
        {
            tank_frame[randHeight[j]].replace ( randWidth[j], fish_collection[j].size(), fish_collection[j] );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `srand(time(NULL))` only once in the program (usually at the beginning of main).

Calling it more than once I *believe* resets the entire sequence which explains why you're always getting the same number (the first one) every time. (And the reason you're always getting the same first one, is that most likely the calls are so close together, the time is the same).

'time(NULL)' returns the number of seconds since 00:00 1st January 1970, which explains why 'srand(time(NULL))' always seeds to the same value: It executes in less than one second, so time(NULL) returns the same value. (See this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time))

Comment: That is correct, or at least if not exactly correct, that is the effect srand has - resetting the sequence.

I don't quite understand why though, as time should be different at a later... well... time...

Comment: @EdwardBird If the program runs fairly quickly standard microsecond time may not have a chance to "tick".

Comment: The problem is that time() returns the current time since epoch in seconds, so it's very likely, in a relatively small number of iterations, that you'll get the same time (and hence the same "random" seed) on every call.

Comment: @hexafraction I just checked here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/ time(NULL) returns a time_t object, which is implemented as the number of seconds since 00:00 1st Jan 1970. (it counts seconds, which explains why)

Comment: Oh, my bad. So seconds it is.

Answer (score 0):

You call `srand()` every time when you call `rand()` function. This is incorrect: `srand()` should be used only once in the beginning of your program, because the value you pass to it sets the whole sequence of further `rand()` values. In this example you always call `srand()` with the same argument (because time updates not very often), thus the `rand()` sequence was always the same, thus call to `rand()` always returned the same value.